# Communicating with a guest virtual machine via host browser

Tags: cgi, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am designing a web based software package that has the potential to become CPU / RAM intensive for select users. The software required the installation of many third party publicly licensed software packages and initial version of the software will likely be distributed as a virtual machine in order to circumvent the need to install and configure the supporting software packages.

Is there a way to have a web browser on users host computer to access software located on a virtual machine running as a guest on the same computer? I am look for a means of shifting the CPU / RAM requirements to the end user machine when required. I would imagine that there are a number of safe guards in place to prevent this behavior.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, it's possible. but depends entirely on your virtualization platform and how you configure the vm<->host networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a headless VM.  Basically, you can run a VM without a GUI as an item on the host computer's network.  It will have its own IP and can be communicated with as though it were an independent machine.

Check out [this link](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html) for info on how to do it in Virtual Box.

Comment: Thanks Grisk -- the link to the Virtual Box document was certainly helpful. I see that what I am proposing should be technically possible given the proper configuration of the guest machine. While I am confident that potential users of the proposed software would be able to download and start the provided virtual machine, the strategy may quickly fall short if advanced configuration of the virtual machine would be required.

Comment: There are a number of tools to use if that is a problem. I regularly use Vagrant to provision VM's to use for the development process, that may be useful to you. You could even start with an existing base-machine such as Scotchbox.